# ROS gazebo sometimes crashing at launch (Groovy)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Two out of three times, it crashes at launch. So eventually I can launch gazebo after few tries but still not a desirable experience. Can someone take a look and check there is some bug/race condition? Or, is this known problem?

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/1047a99e6dee43bddaf7c571057bbb45

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1265/ros-gazebo-sometimes-crashing-at-launch-(groovy)/) by [jys](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/141/jys/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 22 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thanks for the backtrace. The problem is known, and the best solution is to use the stand-alone version of Gazebo. The version shipped in Groovy is out of date.

You can install Gazebo with these instructions: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.4/install

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1